# Automatic instance derivation using newtype

Tags: haskell

(Related question [Even more generalized newtype deriving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12665779/even-more-generalized-newtype-deriving))

I like wrap types

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
newtype Foo = Foo { unFoo :: Int } deriving (Eq, Ord, Enum, Real, Num, Read, Integral, Show)
newtype Var = Var { unVar :: Int } deriving (Eq, Ord, Enum, Real, Num, Read, Integral, Show)
```

to prevent

```
doSomething :: Int -> Int -> Int
doSomething someFoo otherVar
```

**Is possible derive automatically all possible instances?**

(It's not recommended?, Exists a better way?)

Thank you!

Comment: hmmm, it might be possible with template haskell, but really if you're going to derive all possible instances you'd be better off just using a `type` alias instead.

Comment: If the data type is purely internal to your software... just add to the `deriving (...)` clause as needed.

Comment: @bheklilr I think `type` not prevent mix types. @rampion, yes but is a bit annoying (not much, really).

Comment: @josejuan If your `Foo` is identical to an `Int` in every way, except that it's wrapped in an additional constructor, then why do you need `Foo` to be separate?  What do you gain from making that distinction?   If you need to control what values are valid for `Foo`, then use a smart constructor and manually define the `Num` instance.  Otherwise the user won't know any difference between `doSomething 1 2` and `doSomething (Foo 1) (Foo 2)`, they'll behave the same.

Comment: @bheklilr `Adults` and `Children` are all equals except one are `Adults` and the other one `Children`. But I don't like mix `processBook children adults` (when is `processBook adults children`).

Comment: @josejuan then I think you're out of luck, you're going to have to specify all the instances you want, or define them manually for each type.

Comment: Can you say exactly what differs between this question and the one you linked to?

Comment: @DanielWagner he has not solution to their problem "I'd like to write deriving hiding (Special)" I only wish some automatic way to derive all possible instances (instead write at hand)